# Purpose of 62.5% font-size in elastic layouts

Tags: html, css, font-size

There existing a practice to set body font to 62.5 %, so 1 em would be equal to 10 px. Also it is known that this method has some drawbacks.

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

As stated in several articles,

Quote form [1st article](https://csswizardry.com/2011/05/font-sizing-with-rem-could-be-avoided/):

> The 62.5% trick is a common one, and does have its uses in two circumstances:
>
> - You want simpler maths, for example if you are building an elastic layout (width:30em; == width:300px;)
> - <...>

Quote from [another article](http://www.exsertus.be/2013/06/rem-ems-and-px-when-size-does-matter/):

> The 62.5% Hack is a common one and has its uses and drawbacks.
>
> I only recommend using it if you want simpler maths, for example if you are building an elastic layout.

I want to know how exactly 62.5 %-trick helps in building elastic layouts. Some simple examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were setting all your padding/margins with rem - That way you know 1rem = 10px when at a 100% browser zoom.

Comment: 1rem = 10px, actually.

Answer (score 1):

It's a method of getting away from pixel-based font sizes. Consider a font-size of 10px, that refers to it's width, on a monitor that has a resolution of 3840×2160 but the monitor is physically only 13 inches. A 10px character would take up a third of an inch, that's very tiny and hard to see.

My math might be a bit off, but in general the use of non-pixel based font sizes is meant to make choosing font sizes device agnostic. So font's always display at a readable size even on monitors with high & low PPI.